# Swift - How to add a layer on a UIImageView inside of a UICollectionViewCell and keep the parallax effect

Tags: swift, uiimageview, parallax, layer, tvos

I'm working on a tvOS project. This project contains a `UICollectionView` with a `UIImageView` inside of each `UICollectionViewCell`. First of all I'm using `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` on the image, because it looks good when the cell is in focus and I want to have the 'parallax' effect.

When a cell is in focus there should pop up an label over the image(for the title of a product) which is not a problem to make. But I want the title to be good readable so thats why I want to put on a gradient layer on top of the image.

**The problem:**
When I add the gradient layer to the UIImageView, it goes on top of it but it doesn't 'stick' to it. It should go with the image when the user is doing the parallax thing, but it stays at its position and the original image does move underneath the gradient layer

**Screenshot of the problem**
[image: The actual problem]

**The code**

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red:0.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:0.3).cgColor, UIColor(red:1.00, green:0, blue:1.00, alpha:0.3).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.frame = productImageView.focusedFrameGuide.layoutFrame
    gradientLayer.isHidden = true
    self.productImageView.layer.addSublayer(self.gradientLayer)
    
    if (self.isFocused){
        gradientLayer.isHidden = false
    }
    else {
        gradientLayer.isHidden = true
    }
    
}
```

**Additional question**

Is this a bug? Because I still don't figured it out how to fix this problem. Should I give this to Apple?

Answer (score 5):

Apple introduced `overlayContentView` in tvOS 11. You should add your label to this view and it will do the focus for you!

For more information read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/2882128-overlaycontentview?changes=latest_minor

Comment: Anybody know of a way to do this manually before this iOS 11 feature?

Comment: Any idea about how to add the rounded corners when the images is focused (and thus scaled) in tvOS?? Like any other view, icon, movie poster. I have been searching for this for two weeks now, it gets clipped, or worse.

Comment: There are so many incorrect answers on SA for how to handle the layer on a focused tvOS cell.  Apple's code samples never mention or use this property.  This answer correctly identifies `overlayContentView` as the relevant property.